# How to trigger autohotkey script with a download

Tags: script, download, automation, autohotkey

I want to trigger my script every time my Gpodder program downloads an MP3.

Answer (score 0):

I would modularize the script for this. So you could have your main script run in a loop (code below) to check for a .mp3 file in a directory you have set "Gpodder" to download to, and then fire another .ahk file with the script you have in mind.

The following script will check every 60 seconds in `F:\Directory\Path\to\Gpodder\Downloads\` for any .mp3 file (note the wildcard). When one is found, it will run the script at `F:\Path\to\Second_Script.ahk`

```
F2::
Loop, F:\Directory\Path\to\Gpodder\Downloads\*.mp3
{ 
Run, F:\Path\to\Second_Script.ahk
Sleep, 5000 ; Sleep 60 seconds
}
return
```